# Having problems accessing bucket that is not using US region with the .Net SDK

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-s3

I have recently been trying ot write code to add and delete content form an Amazon S3 bucket. I am completely new to Amazon S3 and the AmazonWS .Net SDK.

The bucket region endpoint is http://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com so I constructed my client like this:

```
_s3Client = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(accessKey, awsSecretKey, new AmazonS3Config().WithServiceURL("http://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"));
```

If I leave out the AmazonS3Config bit I get this error:

> A redirect was returned without a new location.  This can be caused by
>   attempting to access buckets with periods in the name in a different
>   region then the client is configured for.

When I put in the AmazonS3Config  bit I no longer get that error but I appear to have no access to this bucket at all or any other bucket that I would usually have access to. Any request I send returns null.

I have tested my code with other buckets that are configured to the standard US region and it all works well. The single difference is in the CreateAmazonS3Client method where I set the config with the EU endpoint.

Could anybody give me some guidance on how I should set up my client to work with a bucket in the EU(Ireland) region. I have been searching for a few hours and every tutorial or document I have followed has not worked so far.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just use the standard endpoint - `s3.amazonaws.com`

```
AmazonS3Config S3Config = new AmazonS3Config {
    ServiceURL = "s3.amazonaws.com",
    CommunicationProtocol = Amazon.S3.Model.Protocol.HTTP
};

AmazonS3 client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(AWS_Key, AWS_SecretKey, S3Config);

PutObjectRequest UploadToS3Request = new PutObjectRequest();
UploadToS3Request.WithFilePath(localPath)
                 .WithBucketName(bucket)
                 .WithKey(key);

client.PutObject(UploadToS3Request);
```

Comment: I had tried that endpoint before but had not put  "CommunicationProtocol = Amazon.S3.Model.Protocol.HTTP" in the config. Adding that did the trick. Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: If you want to use HTTPS, I think you need to use the EU specific endpoint which is `s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`. You were using the Simple Queue Service endpoint. See http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html

Comment: God, I never even spotted the sqs being there instead of s3. I think I just copied it from some post somewhere instead of tackling the Amazon docs properly. I didn't know what was going wrong but it's so obvious now. Looks like I have some reading to do. Thanks again.

Comment: In the latest SDK, you'll need to stick a http:// in front of that ServiceURL to get it working.  This does seem to be the only way to construct a client object that can read both US and EU buckets without throwing.

Comment: Can we fetch region(service url) dynamically?

Answer (score 6):

To whom it may still concern..

With the old AWS SDKs (version 1), you can simply create the S3 client without a region or an `AmazonS3Config`. No need to specify a service URL, it uses the default, mentioned above, for you. The only time you really need the region for work with S3 is when you create a bucket which is probably rarely a requirement for an application.
This works for me and all communication I perform to S3 is over https.

With the new AWS SDK for .Net (version 2 and above) it seems the region parameter is required and in fact the `AmazonS3Client` would throw an exception if not given one. I've tried working around this limitation with specifying a generic `https://s3.amazonaws.com` URL and failed, because the new SDK does not follow the 301 redirect from the default (US-EAST-1 I think) endpoint.

So in summary, best to specify region, even on the old API, to avoid breaking in the future. If your application is making cross-region calls, and are slower (possibly) and more expensive, it's probably best that your code will testify to that.